# JS: Serializing an object with methods (or an instance) to json/string without losing the methods

Tags: javascript, json

Bumped into this while trying to cache objects into localstorage. seems that localstorage currently doesn't support objects with methods/object Instances etc. just POJO that are serialized into a string. In python there's pickle that can handle this (or marshal before it) but I couldn't find a js equivalent. Since I guess I'm not the first Js dev to need this feature I guess there are already proven solutions (either in patterns or external libs) to this problem which I'm missing.

Basically I'm looking for a way to call `serialize(object)` into a json/string and later `deSerialize(objString)` that would return the original object/instance etc.

The answer can be some lib and doesn't have to be part of the js standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [JSONfn](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/jsonfn) do that. It has its own stringify/parse methods that save functions as well as ordinary JSON data.

Comment: can it handle an instance? or just an object?

Comment: It can handle any object with properties and methods. Check out the documentation. :)